# Declare unsigned char[] with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Tags: c++, qt, qttest

I'm trying to set up some unit tests with QtTest and i'd like to use QFETCH.

I am testing the following function :

```
static std::vector<bool> FrameHandler::getBitsFromFrame(unsigned char* data, unsigned char length);
```

It simply converts a array of char into a vector of bits.

So, I set up my test class like this :

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <vector>
#include "FrameHandler.h"

class BusTester : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:

    void bytesToVector_data() {
        QTest::addColumn<unsigned char[]>("Tested");
        QTest::addColumn<unsigned char>("Length");
        QTest::addColumn< std::vector<bool> >("Reference");

        // Test for one byte
        std::vector<bool> oneByte(8, false);
        oneByte[0] = true;
        oneByte[1] = true;
        oneByte[3] = true;
        oneByte[4] = true;

        unsigned char oneByteInput[1]{
            0b11011000
        };

        QTest::newRow("One byte") << oneByteInput << 1 << oneByte;
    }

    void bytesToVector() {
        QFETCH(unsigned char[], tested);
        QFETCH(unsigned char, length);
        QFETCH(std::vector<bool>, reference);

        QCOMPARE(FrameHandler::getBitsFromFrame(tested, length), reference);
    }
};

QTEST_MAIN(BusTester)
#include "bustester.moc"
```

When I do this, the compiler says :

```
expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
         QFETCH(unsigned char[], tested);
```

And also :

```
On line `QTest::addColumn<unsigned char[]>("Tested");`, Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system
```

I thought the two errors were linked, so i added `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(unsigned char[]);` before the class declaration, but then I get this :

> In `qmetatype.h`, expected '>' before '*' token (line 1695)

Is it possible to declare `unsigned char[]` to Qt's QMetaType system ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T) Type T must be constructable, copiable and destructable.
Array doesn match this rules, but you can create wrapper around.

```
struct Arr
{
    unsigned char arr[SIZE];
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Arr );
```

or

```
typedef std::array<unsigned char, SIZE> TArr;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( TArr );
```

But there is one difficulties - SIZE, You have-to declare it

Comment: Or just use an `unsigned char *`

Comment: Yes. But in this case, You have to hold somewhere pointed object to avoid access violation. This this test data, so it could static constants to achieve that.

Comment: Presumably the OP knows what he is doing and now to avoid out of bounds access.

Comment: @arturx64 your answer looks reasonable, i'll try it out as soon as possible !